# Omitting SharePoint Special Character

Tags: jquery, spservices

I am using a SPServices (jQuery Library for SharePoint webservice) to grab list items. I have managed to get the data as follows:

```
<z:row ows_Date_x0020_From="2013-06-03 00:00:00"
 ows_Date_x0020_To="2013-06-05 00:00:00" ows_Approver="9;#MV\tengsung"
 ows_Leave_x0020_Type="1;#AL" ows__ModerationStatus="0" ows__Level="1"
 ows_ID="1" ows_UniqueId="1;#{7A76C1C6-183A-44DE-AE20-DE341A7CADCA}"
 ows_owshiddenversion="4" ows_FSObjType="1;#0" ows_Created="2013-06-03
 17:08:38" ows_Date_x0020_Applied="2013-06-03 18:00:00"
 ows_PermMask="0x7fffffffffffffff" ows_Modified="2013-06-03 17:46:21"
 ows_Employee_x0020_Name="10;#sokyee"
 ows_FileRef="1;#Lists/Leaves/1_.000" ows_MetaInfo="1;#"/>
```

How can I omit the Special SP Characters, e.g. "`10;#Albert`" or "`1;#AL`", and take only the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I do it typically:

```
var leave = $(this).attr("ows_Leave_x0020_Type").split(";#")[1];
```

Meaning for this z:row, get the leave type attribute, split the string on ;# and give me the second item in the array it creates as arrays are zero indexed  to give you AL or [0] to get you the index/ID value of the item.

Comment: I am new to this, may I know what is the value before ";#"?

Comment: updated answer, it's basically an internal ID